Implementing all the combinations in an array
I have this array [10, 20, 30, 40].
I want:
10 20 30 40
20 30 40
30 40

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] myNum = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };
        for (int i = 0; i < myNum.Length; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < myNum.Length - 1; j++)
                Console.WriteLine(myNum[i] + " " + myNum[j]);
    }
}

After I run the program I get:
10 20
10 30
20 30


Your expected result (as you wrote in the question) is NOT all the combinations in the array.

The first thing you should do is review and research some of the answers on this topic already here because there are quite a few very good ones (and with less code than you are using)

"all the combinations"? what about "10 20 30", or "10 20" ... Why only the combinations you mentioned above?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Have you thought about debugging your code? Like stepping throw you code seeing whats in i and j. What values then are referenced by myNum[i],myNum[j]? I mean its a 3 liner and having the ability to debug things is presumably the most basic and relevant skill to have to understand any code. Showing you a solution is presumably counterproductive to your learning effort. Try debugging first.

The example provided for [10, 20, 30, 40] is not all combinations, but

All subrarrays with Length of at least 2 and containing array's last item.

If it's your task then we can query myNum with a help of Linq:
using System.Linq;

...

int[] myNum = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };

var result = Enumerable
  .Range(0, myNum.Length - 1)
  .Select(start => myNum.Skip(start).ToArray());

// Let's have a look at result
foreach (var item in result)
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", item)); 

Fiddle
If you want all combinations with Length at least k == 2 then you can put it as
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;

...

int[] myNum = { 10, 20, 30, 40 };

int k = 2;

var result = Enumerable
  .Range(0, 1 << myNum.Length)
  .Where(mask => BitOperations.PopCount((uint)mask) >= k)
  .Select(mask => myNum.Where((_, i) => (mask & (1 << i)) != 0).ToArray());

// Let's have a look at result
foreach (var item in result)
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", item)); 

Output:
10 20
10 30
20 30
10 20 30
10 40
20 40
10 20 40
30 40
10 30 40
20 30 40
10 20 30 40

